# Possessiveness of a word in quotations

Tags: possessives, quotes

I recently wrote an article about addiction and referred to addiction as a bully and used quotes around "bully" as to not confuse the addiction with another actual human being who is acting unruly.

So when I make "bully" possessive I assume I need to do that inside the quotes as in "bully's" but I'm not exactly sure of the rules around this.

Is it more correct to write "bully's" or restructure the sentence so that I avoid the apostrophe altogether?

> - A "bully's" temperament ...
> - The temperament of a "bully" ...*

--- EDIT ---

The core of my question is that *"bully" 's* is ideologically correct but the grammatical representation is horrendous. Reason being because the *"bully"* represents the addiction and *"bully's"* appears to represent something possessed by an actually bully whereas I want the reader to realize I'm talking about something the addiction possesses, not a bully. How do I make that distinction?

The more I think about this, the more I realize the answer is that I need to avoid using possession on a word that represents an idea. I was hoping this question would lead to an objective answer but it's seemingly over complicated which all but forces it to be subjective. That's against the SE rules so I'll close this. -- nvm it's already closed

Comment: If the linked question does not answer your query, please edit your question to ask particularly about what is not covered.

Comment: I would drop the quotes around your original use of *bully*. It's perfectly fine to say *Addiction is a bully.* We do not normally use quotes around words used metaphorically. For example, we do not say: *Death is a "reaper".*

Comment: Even if you do keep the quotation marks around "bully" the first time you use it in the context of your discussion of addiction-as-a-bully, you needn't continue to include the quotation marks on subsequent occurrences of the word. The point of the quotation marks is to signal to readers, "I'm using this word in a nonstandard way, so be aware of what I'm doing." Thereafter, unless you revert to talking about human bullies at some point, you have performed due diligence in warning readers of your idiosyncratic usage and you can safely dispense with the quotation marks.

Comment: @SvenYargs this hits on the subjective portion of the question at which point it doesn't really matter what I do. I figure common sense will mask the issue and beyond that everyone will have their own opinion so it's pointless to try and satisfy them. Regardless, I dare say I traveled too far down the rabbit hole.. Good times though.